# Microsoft WEB API Get User Info From Microsoft Account

Tags: c#, asp.net, onedrive, live-sdk, outlook-restapi

**Hi All I am New ti Use WEB API and When I start Search about it I got Confused to view that there is lot of details**

live SDK ?
Outlook Rest API
One Drive API and etc ...

I want following Step by Step

Sign IN my Users using their Microsoft Account...
Store their Registration Info (First Name Last Name and Phone ) From Microsoft account to local Database 
Remeber their Log In so They Know that they have Connected their Microsoft Account.
and Manage Their Files On Their One Drive Storage and Their Contacts.

I also Visited Following Links but I can't Understand 
https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted
https://dev.outlook.com/

Please Guide Me Step By Step .... 
First To Login and Get user's Registration Info..

I also Visit this Link .. its make some sense but I don,t like to use java script ... I want to use c# instead

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826521.aspx

http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/ISDK.aspx?category=scenarioGroup_core_concepts&index=0#

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to access both OneDrive and Contacts, I recommend using the [Microsoft Graph API](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/). In broad strokes, you would:

1. Use Open ID/OAuth for authentication (get user's info and access tokens to store in your database)
2. Use Graph REST API to access files and contacts